# Can a polymorphic constant be mapped over a list of *types*?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Haskell hobbyist here - is it possible to map a *polymorphic constant* over a list of *types* in a generic way?

More precisely, consider this snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
  
module Main where

import Data.Kind( Type )

class HasName a where name :: String

instance HasName Int where name = "Int"

instance HasName Double where name = "Double"


class AllNames (ts :: [Type]) where
  allNames :: [String]

instance AllNames '[] where
  allNames = []

instance (HasName t, AllNames rest) => AllNames (t ': rest) where
  allNames = name @t : allNames @rest

  
main :: IO ()
main = print $ allNames @'[Int, Double]
```

Unsurprisingly, this works as expected, i.e., it prints `["Int","Double"]`. However, if I try to generalize the pattern above so that the code can be used with **any** `name`-like polymorphic constant, then I run into problems.

Here's my attempt at generalization:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
  
module Main where

import Data.Kind( Constraint, Type )

--
-- Intended to be the generalized version of 'name'
--
type PolymorphicConstant (c :: Type -> Constraint) (a :: Type) = forall t . c t => a

--
-- Intended to be the generalized version of 'AllNames'
--
class AllPolymorphicConstants (c :: Type -> Constraint) (ts :: [Type]) (a :: Type) where
  allPolymorphicConstants :: PolymorphicConstant c a -> [ a ]

instance AllPolymorphicConstants c '[] a where
  allPolymorphicConstants _ = []

instance (c t, AllPolymorphicConstants c rest a) => AllPolymorphicConstants c (t ': rest) a where
  allPolymorphicConstants f = f @t : allPolymorphicConstants @c @rest @a f
```

Alas, this doesn't compile (btw, I'm using GHC 8.10.7):

```
Main.hs:31:74: error:
    • Could not deduce: c t0 arising from a use of ‘f’
      from the context: (c t, AllPolymorphicConstants c rest a)
        bound by the instance declaration at Main.hs:30:10-91
      or from: c t1
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                  PolymorphicConstant c a
        at Main.hs:31:74
    • In the fourth argument of ‘allPolymorphicConstants’, namely ‘f’
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
        ‘allPolymorphicConstants @c @rest @a f’
      In the expression: f @t : allPolymorphicConstants @c @rest @a f
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: PolymorphicConstant c a (bound at Main.hs:31:27)
        allPolymorphicConstants :: PolymorphicConstant c a -> [a]
          (bound at Main.hs:31:3)
   |
31 |   allPolymorphicConstants f = f @t : allPolymorphicConstants @c @rest @a f
   |                                                                          ^
```

I'm probably missing something basic that makes this sort of generalization impossible - but what is it exactly?

Comment: `newtype PolyConst c a = PolyConst (∀ t . c t => a)` makes this work, in that case you write `allPolymorphicConstants c@(PolyConst f) = f @t : allPolymorphicConstants @c @rest @a c`. Not sure why it doesn't work without the newtype.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Here we need to use something like proxy/tagged. A custom newtype also works, since it's similar to tagged. The key is to avoid ambiguous types, since they don't play well in this case without type-level lambdas. It's a bit tricky and I tried to explain below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wish someone can prove me wrong, but this is one of the few corner cases where we meet a limitation of current GHC and we can not get away from using `Proxy`, `Tagged` or similar "relics" of the past.

## A minimal example

Let's consider a simpler example:

```
class C a where

-- Ambiguous type
type T a = forall t. C t => a
```

Note that, if we have a value `x :: T a`, there is no unambiguous way to use it except with an explicit type argument `x @t`. That's the price to pay for using ambiguous types, but that's fine.

The following code type-checks as expected.

```
foo :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo f = f @t
```

Instead, this does not.

```
-- Error: Could not deduce (C t0) arising from a use of `foo'
foo2 :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo2 = foo
```

This might be surprising at first. Indeed, `foo2` has *exactly* the same type of `foo`, so `foo2=foo` is obviously OK! Yet, it fails. The reason is, once again, ambiguous types, and the thumb rule still is: if something has an ambiguous type, we can not use it if we don't pass additional `@t @a` arguments.

Doing that makes everything work.

```
foo3 :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo3 = foo @t @a
```

The above is a little strange since we can't write (and have not to write) `foo3 @t @a = foo @t @a`. I guess that if GHC forced us to do that, then it could also allow us to "eta-contract the type arguments" everything and write `foo3 = foo`.

Now, what if we eta-expand the value argument (not the type!). We get an error:

```
-- Error: Could not deduce (C t0) arising from a use of `x'
foo4 :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo4 x = foo @t @a x
```

Groan. This is simply `foo3 = foo @t @a` eta-expanded. What's going wrong here? Well, the issue is the same: now we introduced `x :: T a`, and that's an ambiguous type, so we can not use `x` without `@...` arguments. Even if `foo` expects a polymorphic value!

Here we find ourselves unable to escape. GHC sees the polymorphic arguments and adds an implicit type argument abstraction over `x`, adding `(\@t0 -> ...` in front. But that's a kind of syntax we are not allowed to use, and there is no way to capture the fresh type variable `t0`. In other words, we would like to write

```
foo4 :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo4 x = foo @t @a (\@t0 -> x @t0)
```

but we can only write

```
foo4 :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo4 x = foo @t @a (x @something)
```

and there is no way to mention `t0` there. Sigh.

## Using proxies

The only "solution" I can see it to use `Proxy` (or similar relics), and avoid ambiguous types.

```
-- No longer ambiguous
type T a = forall t. C t => Proxy t -> a

foo :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo f = f (Proxy @t)

foo4 :: forall t a. (C t) => T a -> a
foo4 x = foo @t @a x
```

Now we can use `x` as-is since it has no longer an ambiguous type.

Using `Tagged` or wrapping the polymorphic value inside a `newtype` or `data` would also work, since it makes the type no longer ambiguous.

## The original code, proxy-fied

```
type PolymorphicConstant (c :: Type -> Constraint) (a :: Type) 
   = forall t . c t => Proxy t -> a

--
-- Intended to be the generalized version of 'AllNames'
--
class AllPolymorphicConstants (c :: Type -> Constraint) (ts :: [Type]) (a :: Type) where
  allPolymorphicConstants :: PolymorphicConstant c a -> [ a ]

instance AllPolymorphicConstants c '[] a where
  allPolymorphicConstants _ = []

instance (c t, AllPolymorphicConstants c rest a) 
    => AllPolymorphicConstants c (t ': rest) a where
  allPolymorphicConstants f = f (Proxy @t) : allPolymorphicConstants @c @rest @a f
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it !!